# How to find out if the two equal parts of a string are anagrams in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, anagram

I'm trying to write a code that does the following:

1. Takes a number of strings as input
2. Splits each string into two contiguous substrings of equal length
3. Returns the minimum number of characters to change to make the two substrings into anagrams of one another (if it's not possible, it must return -1).

**Sample Input**

```
6
aaabbb
ab
abc
mnop
xyyx
xaxbbbxx
```

**Sample Output**

```
3
1
-1
2
0
1
```

For a more detailed explanation about the problem, kindly check [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/anagram/problem) link (no login or sign-up needed).

I've approached the solution pretty well, but it seems like I'm not getting something right, my output is usually a bit greater or smaller than what's expected, and I really don't know what's causing the problem. Here's my code:

```
n = int(input())
user_input = []

for k in range(n):
    user_input.append(input())

results = []

for i in user_input:
    if len(list(i))%2 == 0:
        left = i[:len(list(i))//2]
        right = i[len(list(i))//2:]

        left_dict = dict((letter,left.count(letter)) for letter in set(left))
        right_dict = dict((letter,right.count(letter)) for letter in set(right))

        if left_dict == right_dict:
            results.append(0)

        else:
            shared_items = {k: left_dict[k] for k in left_dict if k in right_dict and left_dict[k] == right_dict[k]}
            
            results.append(len(left) - len(shared_items))
            

    else:
        results.append(-1)

print(results)
```

I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started great, with calculating the count for each character in both the substrings, but you never used this power technically.

In this statement:

```
shared_items = {k: left_dict[k] for k in left_dict if k in right_dict and left_dict[k] == right_dict[k]}
```

you just calculate items that are in both the dictionary and have same count:

eg. in your 6th testcase:

`xaxbbbxx`

`left_dict` will be `{'b': 1, 'a': 1, 'x': 2}`
`right_dict` will be `{'b': 2, 'x': 2}`

and `shared_item` the way you calculate will give you: `{'x':2}`

But this doesn't correctly list all the items that are shared.

The correct no. of `shared_items` should be : `{'x':2, 'b':1}`

So for that,
What we could then do is calculate the minimum of the item quantities common in the `left_dict` and `right_dict`.
i.e. `min(left_dict[k],right_dict[k])`

the `result.append` statement will also change accordingly:

```
    else:
        shared_items = {k:min(left_dict[k],right_dict[k]) for k in left_dict if k in right_dict}
        
        results.append(len(left)-sum(shared_items.values()))
```

Full execution:

```
n = int(input())
user_input = []

for k in range(n):
    user_input.append(input())

results = []

for i in user_input:
    if len(list(i))%2 == 0:
        left = i[:len(list(i))//2]
        right = i[len(list(i))//2:]

        left_dict = dict((letter,left.count(letter)) for letter in set(left))
        right_dict = dict((letter,right.count(letter)) for letter in set(right))
        if left_dict == right_dict:
            results.append(0)

        else:
            shared_items = {k:min(left_dict[k],right_dict[k]) for k in left_dict if k in right_dict}
            
            results.append(len(left)-sum(shared_items.values()))
            

    else:
        results.append(-1)

print(results)
```

Input:

```
6
aaabbb
ab
abc
mnop
xyyx
xaxbbbxx
```

Output:

```
[3, 1, -1, 2, 0, 1]
```

which you could then ofcourse use and print `'\n'.join(results)` to get the output in the required format.

Comment: That's right! I really appreciate your help! Clear and well-explained solution with patience, which is pretty rare nowadays on StackOverflow :D

Answer (score 1):

Two words are anagrams if the same letters appear with the same occurrencies.

```
from collections import Counter

sl = ["aaabbb", "ab", "abc", "mnop", "xyyx", "xaxbbbxx"]


def f(s):
    if len(s)%2 != 0:
        return -1

    a = s[:len(s)//2]
    b = s[len(s)//2:]

    print(Counter(b) - Counter(a))
    return sum( (Counter(b) - Counter(a)).values() )

list(map(f, sl))
```

```
Counter({'b': 3})
Counter({'b': 1})
Counter({'o': 1, 'p': 1})
Counter()
Counter({'b': 1})

[3, 1, -1, 2, 0, 1]
```